# Getting field data with case and delimiter

Tags: sql-server

I don't know if my question is correct but I've already tried searching through google about this problem seems no answer to my question. All i want to do is to count the violation of each agent.

Violations: Early Parker, Late Parker, Reinforcement

My table looks like this.

```
|Date       | Agent     | Violation    |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|08/10/2019 | John Doe  | Early Parker |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|08/10/2019 | Alex Gee  | Late Parker  |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|08/11/2019 | John Doe  | Reinforcement|
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|08/11/2019 | John Doe  | Early Parker |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|08/12/2019 | Matt Hill | Late Parker  |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

So when I count each Agents violation with this code:

```
ts.Date as [Date],
ts.Agent as [Agent],
count(Case when ts.Remarks = 'Early Parker' then ts.Remarks END) as [Early Parker],

count(Case when ts.Remarks = 'Late Parker' then ts.Remarks END) as [Late Parker],

count(Case when ts.Remarks = 'Reinforcement' then ts.Remarks END) as [Reinforcement]
```

My table be now looked like this, which work fine:

```
|Date       | Agent     | Early Parker | Late Parker | Reinforcement |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|08/10/2019 | John Doe  | 1            | 0           | 0             |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|08/10/2019 | Alex Gee  | 0            | 1           | 0             |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|08/11/2019 | John Doe  | 0            | 0           | 1             |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|08/12/2019 | Matt Hill | 0            | 1           | 0             |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

My Problem is, what if the remarks column contains 2 or more violations ?
like

```
|Date       | Agent     | Violation                  |
+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
|08/10/2019 | John Doe  | Early Parker; Late Parker  |
+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
|08/10/2019 | Alex Gee  | Late Parker                |
+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
|08/11/2019 | John Doe  | Reinforcement; Late Parker |
+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
|08/11/2019 | John Doe  | Early Parker               |
+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
|08/12/2019 | Matt Hill | Late Parker; Reinforcement |
+-----------+-----------+----------------------------+
```

Now the table should be looked like this

```
|Date       | Agent     | Early Parker | Late Parker | Reinforcement |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|08/10/2019 | John Doe  | 1            | 2           | 0             |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|08/10/2019 | Alex Gee  | 0            | 1           | 0             |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|08/11/2019 | John Doe  | 1            | 1           | 1             |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|08/12/2019 | Matt Hill | 0            | 1           | 1             |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

How can I achieve this ? any help please ?

Comment: what is the version of the `SQL Server` ?

Comment: @Squirrel SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use a delimited splitter like [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
SELECT t.Date, t.Agent,
       count(Case when s.Item = 'Early Parker'  then s.Item END) as [Early Parker],
       count(Case when s.Item = 'Late Parker'   then s.Item END) as [Late Parker],
       count(Case when s.Item = 'Reinforcement' then s.Item END) as [Reinforcement]
FROM   yourtable t
       CROSS APPLY DelimitedSplit8K ( t.Remarks , ',' ) s
GROUP BY t.Date, t.Agent
```

Comment: It give me na error "Invalid object name DelimiterSplit8K"

Comment: you need to create the function first. Refer to the link

Comment: I am using your solution, but since I am dealing with a millions of rows, I am not quite sure if the data generated are correct, still checking. . Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your expect output needs correction, that is count of `Late Parker` Violation for `John Doe` on `08/10/2019` is ONE. If I understand correctly, then you will get expected output from following query..

```
create table #v (Date       date, Agent     varchar(10), Violation   varchar(100))

insert #v values
 ('08/10/2019','John Doe','Early Parker; Late Parker ') 
,('08/10/2019','Alex Gee','Late Parker ')
,('08/11/2019','John Doe','Reinforcement; Late Parker ')
,('08/11/2019','John Doe','Early Parker')
,('08/12/2019','Matt Hil','Late Parker; Reinforcement')

select * from #v

select date,Agent, 
  count(case when col.value('.', 'varchar(max)')  = 'Early Parker' then 1 end )'Early Parker'
, count(case when col.value('.', 'varchar(max)')  = 'Late Parker ' then 1 end )'Late Parker '
, count(case when col.value('.', 'varchar(max)')  = 'Reinforcement' then 1 end) 'Reinforcement'
from (
select date,Agent
, convert(xml, '<x>'+REPLACE(Violation, '; ', '</x><x>')+'</x>') b from #v 
) a
cross apply b.nodes('/x') as x(col)
group by date, Agent
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   date       Agent   Early Parker  Late Parker     Reinforcement
2019-08-10  Alex Gee       0            1                 0
2019-08-10  John Doe       1            1                 0
2019-08-11  John Doe       1            1                 1
2019-08-12  Matt Hil       0            1                 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be :

```
    Declare @YourTable table (Date smalldatetime,Agent varchar(50),Violation varchar(50))
    Insert Into @YourTable values
    ('2019-08-10','John Doe','Early Parker; Late Parker'),
    ('2019-08-10','Alex Gee','Late Parker'),
    ('2019-08-11','John Doe','Reinforcement;Late Parker'),
    ('2019-08-11','John Doe','Early Parker'),
    ('2019-08-12','Matt Hill','Reinforcement;Late Parker'),

    ('2019-08-13','Donald','Reinforcement;Late Parker'),
    ('2019-08-13','Donald','Reinforcement;Early Parker'),
    ('2019-08-13','Jake','Early Parker; Reinforcement'),
    ('2019-08-13','Jake','Reinforcement;Early Parker')

    SELECT t.Date, t.Agent,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Early Parker',t.Violation,0 )>=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as [Early Parker],
    SUM(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Late Parker',t.Violation,0 )>=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as [Late Parker],
    SUM(CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Reinforcement',t.Violation,0 )>=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END ) as [Reinforcement]

    FROM @YourTable t  
    group by
    t.Date, t.Agent
    ORDER BY
    t.Date, t.Agent
```

Result:

```
    Date                Agent       Early Parker  Late Parker  Reinforcement
    2019-08-10 00:00:00 Alex Gee    0               1           0
    2019-08-10 00:00:00 John Doe    1               1           0
    2019-08-11 00:00:00 John Doe    1               1           1
    2019-08-12 00:00:00 Matt Hill   0               1           1
    2019-08-13 00:00:00 Donald      1               1           2
    2019-08-13 00:00:00 Jake        2               0           2
```

However when using this query you must ensure :

- The violation token is distinct and consistent in length and spacing between token words, for instance adding new data like 'Reinf' will produce undesired ouput, since 'Reinf' is part of '**Reinf**orcement' string and the CHARINDEX() will produce output greater than 0.
- The violation data column values will only contain a combination of distinct violation token ,so 'Early Parker; Late Parker ; Late Parker' will only count for one 'Late Parker' not two.
- You've been warned..;)

So there you are, several answers to choose from...Happy coding..